# Select statement with offset in like

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have an entry "123456789" in my table.

```
Select * from map where col like '%1%5%6%7%9'.
```

I want to retrieve the records where the order of the input sequence matches, but i also want to ensure that the distance between any 2 matching digits is less than 2.

Is there any way i can specify an offset ?

[image]

The input is 189, and it selects the record, but i want 1.8.9 to be within 2 of each other. 12879 would be an acceptable output but 123456789 would not be.

Comment: This sounds really theoretically. Can you show example data and expected output?

Comment: What exactly is a matching digit?  You mean adjacent digit?

Comment: &hogan. Yes i meant adjacent digits.

Comment: &juergen. I have added an image and little more detail for clarity.

Comment: If you want users to get a notice of your reply use the `@` not the `&`

Comment: If you want a specific number of characters between, you can use an underscore.  It's a wild card for exactly one character.  So two underscores would be 2 characters, so something like `WHERE col LIKE '1__5'` would match `1245` but not `125` or `12345`.  If you need 1 or 2 positions apart, I guess you could do something crazy with ORs.  But what on earth are you actually trying to do?  This sounds pretty un-realistic to me so far.

Comment: @Andrew I'm trying to match the input with a template. The closer adjacent digits are to each other, better the match.

Comment: But why do you care how close together (or far apart) the digits are?  What you're asking for sounds incredibly complex to me.  Is the string a fixed length?  Is there really a max distance the digits can be apart?  I think you'd need some sort of recursive function and/or stored procedure for this.

Comment: @Andrew The digits represent a direction, and the offset was for occasions where there is a small deviation in the direction, i want to check that it resumes in the input's direction by increasing the search's scope.

Answer (score 1):

Below statement requires 3 to 5 characters between 1 and 5:

```
SELECT * FROM map WHERE col LIKE '%1___%5%6%7%9' AND col NOT LIKE '%1______%5%6%7%9%'
```

Using `_`s you may force any count of characters.

EDIT: Character corrected. Source: [SQLite expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Check in [this SQL Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/528b6/1).

Comment: It does not seem to work in sqlite. Also i want to restrict it to 1-3 characters between 1 and 5, not more than 3.

Comment: Thanks LS_dev. I looked at _ earlier, but what if the entry is 1 digit adjacent to it, then it skips the entry. if the entry is 159, then it would fail.